# No text shown in dialog box (react js dialog box)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-dialog#dialogprompt-generators for my notification generating module. but only display buttons and no any text message shown in dialogbox..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET1wb.png)

```
onClick () {
  this.dialog.show({
    title: 'Greedings',
    body: 'How are you?',
    actions: [
      Dialog.CancelAction(),
      Dialog.OKAction()
    ],
    bsSize: 'small',
    onHide: (dialog) => {
      dialog.hide()
      console.log('closed by clicking background.')
    }
  })
}
```

This is the code part i used for that..Help me..

I have used material dashboard react free template for my project development, So in this dialog box doesn't work, but when i use codesandbox, it works properly, doesn't it work with material dashboard? .I can't understand why,If you know, Help me..

codesandbox.io/s/amazing-glade-lh5tl

```
import React from "react"; 

import firebase from "../../config/firebase.js"; 
import PropTypes from "prop-types"; 
import carfix from "./s.jpg"; 
// react plugin for creating charts 
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist"; // @material-ui/core 
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"; 
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon"; // @material-ui/icons 
import Store from "@material-ui/icons/Store"; 
import Warning from "@material-ui/icons/Warning"; 
import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange"; 
import LocalOffer from "@material-ui/icons/LocalOffer"; 
import Update from "@material-ui/icons/Update"; 
import ArrowUpward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowUpward"; 
import AccessTime from "@material-ui/icons/AccessTime"; 
import Accessibility from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility"; 
import BugReport from "@material-ui/icons/BugReport"; 
import Code from "@material-ui/icons/Code"; 
import Cloud from "@material-ui/icons/Cloud"; // core components 
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.jsx"; 
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.jsx"; 
import Table from "components/Table/Table.jsx"; 
import Tasks from "components/Tasks/Tasks.jsx"; 
import CustomTabs from "components/CustomTabs/CustomTabs.jsx"; 
import Danger from "components/Typography/Danger.jsx"; 
import Card from "components/Card/Card.jsx"; 
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.jsx"; 
import CardIcon from "components/Card/CardIcon.jsx"; 
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.jsx"; 
import CardFooter from "components/Card/CardFooter.jsx"; 
import WorkAssign from "pages/work_assignmt.js"; 
import WorkDone from "pages/work_done.js";  
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap' 
import Dialog from 'react-bootstrap-dialog'
import { bugs, website, server } from "variables/general.jsx";
import {   dailySalesChart,   emailsSubscriptionChart,   completedTasksChart } from "variables/charts.jsx";
import dashboardStyle from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.jsx";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      field1:0,
      field2:0,
      field3:0,
      isDialogOpen: false
    };   }

  onClick () {
    this.dialog.show({
        title: 'Greedings',
        body: 'How are you?',
        actions: [
          Dialog.CancelAction(),
          Dialog.OKAction()
        ],
        bsSize: 'small',
        onHide: (dialog) => {
          dialog.hide()
          console.log('closed by clicking background.')
        }
      })   }

  componentWillMount = async() =>{
    this.setFieldData();   };


  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });   };

  handleChangeIndex = index => {
    this.setState({ value: index });   };

  setFieldData = async() => {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("Daily Work Data").child("02-10-2019").child("Field 1"); 
    var sum=0;



    var ref = firebase.database().ref("Daily Work Data").child("02-10-2019").child("Field 2"); 
    sum=0;



    this.setState({field2: sum}); 

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("Daily Work Data").child("02-10-2019").child("Field 3"); 
    sum=0;

    await ref.once('value',function (snapshot) {       

      snapshot.forEach(element => {
        sum = sum + element.val().amount;
      });  
    });  

    this.setState({field3: sum}); 


  };


  render() {   const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
       className="App"
       style={{
       backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(20,100,20,0.5), rgba(9, 93, 225, 0.0)),url(${carfix})`
       }}>

     <div className="wrappe">
      <div>
        <Dialog ref={(component) => { this.dialog = component }} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <Card>
            <Button variant="underlined"      
            onClick={this.onClick}>
              <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
                  <CardIcon color="warning">
                      <i class="material-icons">notifications_active</i>
                  </CardIcon>
                      <p className={classes.cardCategory}></p>
                     <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>New Notifications</h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardFooter stats>
                <div className={classes.stats}>
                  <hr/>
                </div>
              </CardFooter>
            </Button>
          </Card>
          </GridItem>


          <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <Card>
            <Button variant="underlined"           
             onClick={this.onClick}>
              <CardHeader color="primary" stats icon>
                <CardIcon color="primary">
                   <i class="material-icons">pan_tool</i>
                </CardIcon>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}></p>
                  <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Pending Notifications</h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardFooter stats>
                 <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <hr/>
                 </div>
              </CardFooter>
             </Button>
            </Card>
          </GridItem>


          <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <Card>
            <Button variant="underlined" 
            onClick={this.onClick}>
              <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
                <CardIcon color="danger">
                   <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>
                </CardIcon>
                   <p className={classes.cardCategory}></p>
                   <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Responded Notifications</h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardFooter stats>
                <div className={classes.stats}>
                  <hr/>                 
                </div>
              </CardFooter>
             </Button>
          </Card>
          </GridItem>

        </GridContainer>

        <div>       
      </div>
    </div>   </div>  </div>
    );   } }

Dashboard.propTypes = {   classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired };

export default withStyles(dashboardStyle)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Is it possible to share a bit more of your component code, or get a working codesandbox the repros your issue for someone to look at?

Comment: FYI, here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cannon-lidjs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to a codesandbox I threw together to see if I could repro. It "works" for me but this sandbox is also likely missing **a lot** of CSS. Feel free to fork it and play around, update your question with more details.

Comment: Yes, it works for me also in codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-glade-lh5tl but when i use it in my react component it doesn't work .I can't understand the reason. I use material dashboard free  react template for my project. In this, this doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, updated my sandbox with the bootstrap dependency and CSS. Can you share your component code then, and any styling file/CSS/etc?

Comment: I share my code

Comment: Looks correct, and we know it is functional. Do you happen to have the `react-devtools` chrome extension installed? Or can you use the browser's inspect tool to inspect the nodes of that modal to see if the text is there but colored the same as the background (for some reason)?

Comment: I try to change background color, but can't.